# JS tree Loading time issue

Tags: javascript, json, jstree

I have implemented the Tree with js tree and here i'm getting lot of time(Around 1 min) when loading the tree..

I wanna to find the way to reduce the time and i have over `5000 nodes` in my implementaion.

**In my view**

```
$("#tree").jstree({

        checkbox: {
            real_checkboxes: true,
            real_checkboxes_names: function (n) { return [("check_" + (n[0].id || Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10000))), n[0].id] }
        }, "plugins": ["themes", "html_data", "checkbox", "sort", "ui"]
    }).bind('check_node.jstree', function (event, data) {
        $('#SearchView').show();

    }).delegate("a", "click",
        function (event, data) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

`html` for load `js tree`

```
            <tbody>
                <div id="tree">
                    <ul>
                       @HtmlHelpers.RenderjsTree(Model.CurrentNode)
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </tbody>
```

`RenderjsTree` will recursively call and load the tree nodes.. any way to reduce the time?

Comment: If you're using `jstree`.... have you tried the option `progressive_render`?

Comment: in my RenderjsTree method only the node name will be pushed to the tree..i treid progressive_render. no more luck

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to approach this slow loading problem.

One way is to use the ajax method in the json_data plugin of jstree. Mike Tyka has given a pretty neat description of doing that here - http://www.miketyka.com/2012/10/lazy-loading-with-jstree-and-ajax/

Another way is via a simple javascript method - if you are open to using the v3 of jstree which is still in beta version. In my project I had around 2200 nodes and the json data came from the server side via a single ajax call in less than a second. But the json parsing took around 8-10 seconds till which the page just stopped responding. Jstree v3 has a method of getting the data of a node from a function when the node is opened. I used that method and the page now loads in just under 2 seconds.

```
function initiate_jstree() {
$("#tree_container").jstree({
    "core": {
        "data": getTree,
        "themes":{
            "icons":false
        },
    },
    "plugins": [ "themes", "ui" ,"types"]

});

}
function makeTreeData(node){
if(node.original && node.original.actualData){
    data=node.original.actualData;
}else{
    data=gData;
}
treeData=[];
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    iter=data[i];
    item={"text": iter.data};
    if(iter.children){
        item["children"]=true;
        item["actualData"]=iter.children;            
    }
    treeData.push(item);
}
return treeData;
}
var getTree = function (obj, cb) {
console.log("called");
data=makeTreeData(obj);
cb.call(this,
    data);
}

initiate_jstree();
```

The gdata variable here is a global variable in which the data to be loaded is stored in json format.
Here is the code on jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Lge8C/